# Flutter URL launcher Google Maps crashes App

Tags: google-maps, url, flutter, dart, crash

A couple of days ago launching both Google Maps and Apple Maps perfectly fine. I updated Flutter to its newest Version while on master channel to 1.13.1. I assume after updating it stopped working. So I changed channels to beta and tried, but still not working. When trying to launch Google Maps or Apple Maps the IOS app crashes and I  neither understand the error nor did I find something on the internet.

Any help is much appreciated.

My UI code:

```dart
ListTile(
                 title: Text("Launch Google Maps", textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                  onTap: () async {
                    final String clubName =
                        clubs[index].name.toString().replaceAll(" ", "+");
                    print("Name: $clubName"); // 'Flawless+Club'
                    final String clubCity = clubs[index].stadt;
                    print("Name: $clubCity"); // 'London'
                    final String newGoogleUrl =
                        "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=$clubName+$clubCity";

                    if (await canLaunch(newGoogleUrl)) {
                      await launch(newGoogleUrl);
                    } else {
                      throw 'Could not launch $newGoogleUrl';
                    }
                  },
                ),
```

Flutter doctor -v Ouput:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.12.13+hotfix.3, on Mac OS X 10.15.1 19B88, locale en-DE)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.3 at /Library/Flutter
    • Framework revision 57f2df76d7 (2 days ago), 2019-12-05 21:23:21 -0800
    • Engine revision ac9391978e
    • Dart version 2.7.0


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/murat/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.2.1, Build version 11B500
    • CocoaPods version 1.8.4

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 35.3.1
    • Dart plugin version 183.6270
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.40.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.7.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Error when tapping the ListTile:

```
Lost connection to device.
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c4f02e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff50b97b20 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   Foundation                          0x00007fff2578c55b -[__NSConcreteURLComponents initWithString:] + 0
    3   CoreServices                        0x00007fff24e970bd -[_LSURLOverride initWithOriginalURL:checkingForAvailableApplications:newsOnly:] + 151
    4   CoreServices                        0x00007fff24e97992 -[_LSURLOverride initWithOriginalURL:newsOnly:] + 25
    5   CoreServices                        0x00007fff24e982ae _ZN14LaunchServices12URLOverridesL20getURLOverrideCommonEP5NSURLb + 399
    6   CoreServices                        0x00007fff24e9810e -[LSApplicationWorkspace(LSURLOverride) URLOverrideForURL:] + 14
    7   UIKitCore<…>
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: Try using the stable channel and then running `flutter clean`.

Comment: I can't use the stable channel, because I need to use at least Dart SDK version 2.6.0. I have some dependencies which require that Dart SDK version.

Comment: Hey thanks for posting this issue. I had the same error being thrown but instead of it being for google maps it was for phone numbers. The phone numbers were not formatted correctly for the canLaunch and launch functions. It only threw the error on IOS too

Comment: Yea, unfortunately, the error code is not really helpful. Debugging every value helped to figure that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue solved.

I had in my `club[index].stadt`, which is a list of cities, a city with umlauts as "ä,ö,ü".

By adding 
`final String clubCity = clubs[index].stadt.toString().replaceAll("ü", "ue");` it solved the issue. Because, whenever a city with a umlaut was called within the url, it crashed the app!

Holy cow, that took me ages!

Comment: Wie sagt man "`holy cow"" [auf Deutsch](https://german.stackexchange.com/)? :-)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error.
My problem was that I was using this url which contain a name for the waypoint.

`'https://maps.apple.com/?q=' + '$name' + '&ll=$lat,$lon';`

If the waypoint name (`$name`) contains spaces like 'New York' `launch_url` is not converting the space character to %20.

I fixed it by using `name.toString().replaceAll(' ', "%20")`.
Full url example:
`https://maps.apple.com/?q=' + name.toString().replaceAll(' ', "%20") + '&ll=$lat,$lon'`

Comment: Thanks, that helps as well. Unfortunately, there is nothing within the error code, but issue solved :)

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, `onTap` doesn't play nicely with the `async` keyword. I would extract the logic into another method. `build` Methods shouldn't even contain logic in them, they should be for UI only since they should be cheap to run and can be called at any time for any reason.

```
onTap: () => myFunction(clubs, index),

// the function
void myFunction(var clubs, int index) async {
    final String clubName = clubs[index].name.toString().replaceAll(" ", "+");
    print("Name: $clubName"); // 'Flawless+Club'
    final String clubCity = clubs[index].stadt;
    print("Name: $clubCity"); // 'London'
    final String newGoogleUrl = "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=$clubName+$clubCity";

    if (await canLaunch(newGoogleUrl)) {
        await launch(newGoogleUrl);
    } else {
        throw 'Could not launch $newGoogleUrl';
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right they shouldn't contain logic but it's for prototyping reasons. I extracted that function but still crashes.

Comment: Try this: https://medium.com/softway-blog/google-maps-url-launcher-in-flutter-54cf6388b381

Comment: Already read this article. That's not solving my issue. That is just how the author implemented Google Maps. My issue is different. I need to use the URL launcher to launch google maps to give me a direction. I used it before and it worked. But now it doesn't. Still, appreciate your help!

Comment: If you used "https://google.com" does it work or does it still crash?

Comment: It still crashes, unfortunately.

Comment: Surround `launch` in a try catch statement and print the error (if any)

Comment: just solved the issue. Posted the solution above. It was because of the umlauts within the german language.
Still, it was my mistake to write "London" as a outcome of the print statement.

Comment: Ah wouldn't of known that haha

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same symptoms but my issue turned out to be in `&waypoints=` part of the URL. Apparently android would be able to digest the following URL (example):

`https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=1.11,-0.123&destination=2.22,-0.456&waypoints=1.11,-0.123|1.67,-0.245|2.22,-0.456&travelmode=driving&dir_action=navigate`

while for ios version I had to explicitly convert `|` signs within `waypoints` to `%7C` so it would look like this:

`https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=1.11,-0.123&destination=2.22,-0.456&waypoints=1.11,-0.123%7C1.67,-0.245%7C2.22,-0.456&travelmode=driving&dir_action=navigate`